# Assigning values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following function:

```
public static function toArray($key, $value) {

    $e = explode('.', $key);

    $return = array();

    for($i = count($e) - 1; $i >=  0; $i--) {

        $return = array($e[$i] => $return);

    }

    return $return;

}
```

and the output:

```
Array
(
    [app] => Array
        (
            [shifts] => Array
                (
                    [total] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And desired output:

```
Array
(
    [app] => Array
        (
            [shifts] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

What happens here is that a string is given and and creates a multi-dimensional array  using the dot as the delimiter. However, I wish to assign the last array a value given by the function. This example is assuming that the string input is: **"apps.shifts.total"** with a value of 3. I'm trying to find an elegant way to achieve this without going into useless loops. Any inspiration would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initialization step is wrong.

Try:

```
public static function toArray($key, $value) {
    $e = explode('.', $key);
    $return = $value; // MODIFIED HERE
    for($i = count($e) - 1; $i >=  0; $i--) {
        $return = array($e[$i] => $return);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

What you basically do is cascade to the top. But you start with an empty array. Instead, you can simply start with the value and cascade the array around it.

**Example** (using interactive `php -a`):

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > function toArray($key, $value) {
php {     $e = explode('.', $key);
php {     $return = $value; // MODIFIED HERE
php {     for($i = count($e) - 1; $i >=  0; $i--) {
php {         $return = array($e[$i] => $return);
php {     }
php {     return $return;
php { }
php > var_dump(toArray('apps.shifts.total',3));
array(1) {
  ["apps"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["shifts"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["total"]=>
      int(3)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Funny enough is that I had just realized what my mistake was and needed to assign the value instead of initializing an array. Thanks for reinforcing!